# Verify redirect with unit test in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Is there an easy way to verify in a unit test that a controller action is indeed redirecting to a specific page?

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Create(ProductModel newProduct)
{
    this.repository.CreateProduct(newProduct);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So in my test, I would need to verify that the controller is actually redirecting.

```
ProductController controller = new ProductController(repository);

RedirectToRouteResult result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Create(newProduct);

bool redirected = checkGoesHere;
Assert.True(redirected, "Should have redirected to 'Index'");
```

I'm just not sure how to do the verification.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
Assert.IsNull(result.RouteValues["controller"]); // means we redirected to the same controller
```

and using [MvcContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) you could write this unit test in a much more elegant way (you don't even need to cast to a `RedirectToRouteResult`):

```
// arrange
var sut = new ProductController(repository);

// act
var result = sut.Create(newProduct);

// assert
result
    .AssertActionRedirect()
    .ToAction("Index");
```

Comment: This MvcContrib library is fantastic!

Answer (score 11):

Try this...

```
var result = sut.Create(newProduct) as RedirectToRouteResult;
Assert.Equal(result.RouteValues["action"], "Index");
```

And if you are passing a parameter in redirection you can do something like this...

```
var result = sut.Create(newProduct) as RedirectToRouteResult;
Assert.Equal(result.RouteValues["action"], "Index");
Assert.Equal(result.RouteValues["Parameter Name"], "Parameter Value");
```

Hope this helps :)